# Twilio: Create two outgoing calls and join the conference using Python

Tags: python, django, twilio, conferencing

I am trying to create a conferencing app with max 2 speakers using Twilio using Python/Django. However, in the docs I found out that you can do this by having inbound calls. but, my business model doesnt work like that. Is there a way for this to work like:

- My Twilio number calls number 1
- My Twilio number calls number 2
- Twilio brings two channels to a new conference

I've tried this solution:
[Twilio how to make two outbound calls and join(conference) them using node js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43919831/twilio-how-to-make-two-outbound-calls-and-joinconference-them-using-node-js)
but it didn't help me much..

Here's my code:

```
@csrf_exempt
def conference(request):
    print("success")
    response = VoiceResponse()
    dial = Dial()
    dial.conference('Rooxm 1234')
    response.append(dial)
    print(response)
    return HttpResponse('')

def call(number):
    client = Client(TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID,TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN)
    call = client.calls.create(
        url='https://<blahblah_removed_purposefully>.ngrok.io/conf/',
        to='+' + str(number),
        from_='<removed_my_twilio_num>'
    )
    print(call.sid)

def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = CallForm(request.POST)

        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            #print(dir(form.data.values))
            call(form.cleaned_data['inline'])
            call(form.cleaned_data['outline'])
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = CallForm()
    return render(request, 'CallForm.html', {'form': form})
```

This gave me an error message during the call which is:
"An application error has occurred. Goodbye"

And I also get this in the debugger:
"Error on line 1 of document : Premature end of file. "

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Okay so, I figured this out. The only thing that was needed to make that setup work is I had to modify the response, add the xml string there and then set the content_type of the returned object.

```
return HttpResponse(str(response),content_type='application/xml')
```