# twilio join two outbound calls not working in node js

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-programmable-voice

As per the documentation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43919831/twilio-how-to-make-two-outbound-calls-and-joinconference-them-using-node-js), I have created the below script but its not working.

```
const accountSid = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
const authToken = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

connectNumbers('+1xxxxxxxxxxx','+1xxxxxxxxx');

function connectNumbers(number1, number2) {
  [number1, number2].forEach(function(number) {
    client.calls.create({
      url: 'https://2f3b18f01640.ngrok.io/voice/callConference.xml',
      to: number,
      from: '+1xxxxxxxxxxx',
    })
    .then((call) => process.stdout.write(`Called ${number}`));
  })
}
```

Twiml [link](https://2f3b18f01640.ngrok.io/voice/callConference.xml) produces the following xml:

```
<Response>
<Dial>
<Conference>My conference</Conference>
</Dial>
</Response>
```

Can anyone please tell me what I did wrong.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: there is no error showing but calls are not connected. this is the output: "Called +18778423210 Called +16174025654"

Comment: @Alan in twilio debugger I found the following message: An attempt to retrieve content from https://2f3b18f01640.ngrok.io/voice/callConference.xml returned the HTTP status code 405. But that xms is valid only

Comment: @Alan i missed to add 'GET' method. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

As per the post [here](https://brodan.biz/blog/debugging-twilio-http-405-not-allowed/) found the solution. Returned HTTP status code 405 that means I missed to add 'GET' method. Now its working fine.

```
function connectNumbers(number1, number2) {
  [number1, number2].forEach(function(number) {
    client.calls.create({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'https://2f3b18f01640.ngrok.io/voice/callConference.xml',
      to: number,
      from: '+1xxxxxxxxxxx',
    })
    .then((call) => process.stdout.write(`Called ${number}`));
  })
}
```

Comment: Great, also, I noticed a .catch block is also missing (if the promise fails), so that may have also provided some insight.